# Comparing a variable to upper and lower case letters

Tags: string, tcsh

So I want to validate a response of a user in tcsh script and that's what I have so far

```
set var1="temp"
    while($var1 != [yY] && $var1 != [Yy][Ee][Ss] && $var1 != [Nn] && $var1 != [Nn][Oo])
            echo "Do you want to create a backup directory ? :"
        set response=&< 
        if ($response == [yY] || $respose == [Yy][Ee][Ss]) then
            mkdir backup
            echo "Backupd directory created \n"
        else if($response == [nN] || $response == [Nn][Oo]) then
            echo "No backup directory is created \n"
        else
            echo "Please enter a valid respose ! \n"
            var1=$response
        endif 
    end
```

**I basically want the user to either input Y,y,Yes,N,n,No and of course I also allow for a combination of small case and upper case in yes and now.**

But when I run the script, it gives me an error saying `[yY]: No match.`

So I am guessing something is wrong when comparing $var1 to [Yy]. Basically I am validating the user input.

And cai reassign `var1` like I did, `var1=$response`, or do I have to use set again >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `!~`, "does not match regular expression", rather than `!=`, "is not equal to".

For `$var =~ regexp` and `$var !~ regexp`, the pattern on the right should not be quoted. For `==` and `!=`, you may quote the part on the right (and in fact I'd encourage this).

Since `!=` expects a string, "`[yY]` was not parsed as a regular expression. Rather, the shell expanded it to "any file whose name is `y` or `Y`". And since you didn't have one, the shell complained.

This sort of thing, by the way, is why I prefer not to write scripts in tcsh, even though I use it as my interactive shell.

Comment: I got that part thanks alot. But I have one question.

Can I reassign $var1 using var1=$response or do I have to use set again !

Comment: I assume you've tried both. What's the value of `$var1` after each one?